# Android Native library: Runtime error when trying to load JNI native library

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

The problem I am having seems to be similar to other "failed to load native library" problems. But from what I have come up with, my problem is caused by not being able to open private libraries in API >= 24. [source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html/). And I am running Android O. My JNI library should be local, since it is generated.

I am getting the Runtime error:

```
E linker  : library "/system/lib64/libnative_lib_jni.so" 
("/system/lib64/libnative_lib_jni.so") needed or dlopened by
"/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace:  
[name="classloader-namespace"]
```

I am certain that my Java code, JNI bridge and C++ code is correctly implemented. The library is also being found, but cannot access it, as seen in the error.

The source is just saying that apps needs to be updated in order to avoid these errors, but there is nothing about solving it. Could it be that my generated JNI library is private, thus giving me Runtime error, according to the source, or could there be something else that causes the error.

In my .mk file:

```
LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libnative_lib_jni
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libnative_lib_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
$(call all-cpp-files-under, app/src/main/cpp)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Try unzipping the .apk to find out if the library makes its way there, and if name of the library file found in .apk is in fact libnative_lib_jni.so .

Comment: The .so is not generated in the .apk. It tries to open the .so file from another directory. Does it have to be in the .apk, if so, how do I get it to be generated in the .apk?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you use to load the library in Java? Maybe the "lib" prefix messes up your linking..

Comment: @RisKakaN the .so file does not have to be in the .apk, but if it's not there, you need provide a reliable way of delivering the .so to device. Including it in .apk makes the process a lot easier (especially if only your app uses the .so). In your .mk file try changing LOCAL_MODULE value to "native_lib_jni", and LOCAL_SRC_FILES to the full path to your .so

Comment: @Markus There shouldn't be anything wrong with the java code. It's just a static block that contains System.loadLibrary("native_lib_jni")

Comment: @SolutionMill it does not work when I add a path to the lib. NOTE: So I forgot to say, I am working in an AOSP environment. What happens when I build the app with my .mk file, is that the .so file gets generated on the target together with the .apk, but they are not in the same dir. So the .apk will then find where the .so file is, which it does according to the error, but it is not able to open it.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with Android O, according to the source I linked. And nobody seems to have encountered this problem before, since it is kind of new.

Comment: If you run the app on platform <26 it works well?

Comment: @Markus I haven't had the chance to run it on <26, it takes forever to rebuild the target to <26, and emulators are not working on my linux ubuntu vm. According to the source I linked, it would only work for <24, but it doesn't really seem to be reasonable, because why wouldn't android allow JNI on >23. There must be some other solution to this rather than going back to <24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of investigation, trial and errors, I found the solution.
So on Android 24 and higher, you are not able to open private libraries from /system on the target, and this affected me when trying to get JNI to work on Android O (API 26).

The solution is to move the generated jni lib out of /system. I put it in /data/..., which is not the system. Although you might need root access to access this directory. However, by only moving your jni lib won't solve the problem, you also have to push libc++.so to the same location. This libc++.so should be in your system/lib64 either on the target or on the pc. I did adb push from pc to the target.

At last you have to specify this in the Java code:

```
static {
    System.load("/data/.../libc++.so");
    System.load("/data/.../libnative_lib_jni.so");
}
```

IMPORTANT: loading the libc++.so first is a must.

So by using the System.load(), you are not longer loading from the shared libs, but now it points to the location where you put your libs.

Note: This folder structure is on the target. So I am accessing the libs from the target, and not from the pc.